# Error while using command line command to load firefox in lubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, 14.04, firefox, lubuntu

I have tried to load firefox using command line command in Lubuntu 14.04. Firefox is loading, but not loading as expected.(used -fullscreen)

```
firefox -fullscreen
```

when I execute the command am also getting the below error

(process:7411): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

please help to load firefox in fullscreen mode from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://ananddrs.com/2014/03/07/firefox-fullscreen/

Summary:

Firefox doesn't have -fullscreen [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)

You can use xdotool and create a shell script as follows.

```
firefox http://www.google.com & # one can use any url
sleep 5
xdotool key F11 # hit full screen
```

Comment: But am also getting the same error without -fullscreen

Comment: That looks like just a warning. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1160569 I am assuming firefox starts up fine despite of the error shown.